# File_Get_Contents() works but automattic/woocommerce client does not. [woocommerce_rest_cannot_view]

Tags: php, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am able to pull orders, from my shop, with a simple file_get_contents(), but I cant get the automattic/woocommerce php library to work. And by 'work' I mean that it does connect and try to pull the orders, but the store not allowing it.  (error: [woocommerce_rest_cannot_view] ).  I have been successful pulling orders, with the library, on a different woo install.

Here's my code: (i've played with the options a bit, no luck)

```
function d($var){var_dump($var);}

$woocommerce = new Client(
    "https://{$domain}.com/", 
    $ckey, 
    $csec, 
    array( 'wp_api' => true
         ,'version' => 'wc/v2' 
         ,'verify_ssl' => false
         ,'queryStringAuth' => false
        )
);

try {
   $results = $woocommerce->get('orders');
} catch (HttpClientException $e) {
   d( $e->getMessage() );
        // Error: Sorry, you cannot list resources. [woocommerce_rest_cannot_view]
   d(  $e->getRequest()->getUrl() );
        // https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v2/orders 
   d(  $e->getRequest()->getparameters() ); 
       // empty array 
}


$res = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://{$domain}.com/wp-json/wc/v2/orders?consumer_key={$ckey}&consumer_secret={$csec}&per_page=99"));
d($res );
// works, full list of orders.
```

Comment: What is this Client class? The file_gets_content has your credentials as get params. What does Client do?

Comment: The client is Automattic\WooCommerce\Client from  https://packagist.org/packages/automattic/woocommerce

Answer (score 0):

After a short look in the documentation you posted in your comments: 
read the docs! Especially the part  about `$lastRequest->getBody()`

You only do the get request, but dont read the reaponse body.